# What counts as "knowing some facts about the target's life" for the purposes of imprisonment or other spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Pathfinder has a spell called [Imprisonment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/imprisonment):

> ...  If you know the target's name and some facts about its life, the target takes a -4 penalty on its save.

My problem with this is that "knowing some facts about the target's life" is a quite nebulous term, ripe for metagaming. There are all kinds of things that you may know about someone, but which ones count as being about their life?

- Does knowing their class count?
- Does knowing the name of a relative count?
- Does knowing details of their birth count?
- Does knowing details about their place of living count
- Does knowing details about their physical appearance count?
- Does knowing game-related details like attributes count?
- Does knowing about their reputation count?
- Does knowing about their knowledge or beliefs count?
- Does knowing what they had for lunch count?
- And scores of other things you may know about someone that may or may not count as "about its life", including intensely private stuff that I won't elaborate on here.

Also, how much do you need to know about their life? Is one fact enough or do you need more? Do different types of facts have different weightings?

It all sounds really vague, open for interpretation and rules lawyering and deep discussions about whether "they fell out of a tree at age 5" counts as "facts about their life", which distracts from the actual game.

I'm curious whether there's a RAW about this or even a generally accepted interpretation. I realize that most groups would probably not care about details like this, but some groups can get really worked up about this kind of stuff.

Comment: "RAI" here means something specific - usually that a developer involved in the system has commented on a rule. Deleting "RAI" and changing that last para first sentence ending to "a generally accepted interpretation" still works and may be closer to what you mean?

Comment: @NeilSlater Ah, I thought it meant "Rules as Interpreted", meaning you can create your own interpretation.

Comment: Sorry I should have unabbreviated. RAI is nearly always read as "Rules as Intended"  here, as in "what the designer intended to happen, even if the rules as written don't properly capture that"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any RAW or official RAI, but if you look at the spells [Scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying) (which isn't the exact same, but gives more detail) it talks about 1st hand, second hand or familiar knowledge of the person.  You could also look at [True Resurrection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-resurrection) because it talks about how to unambiguously identifying the deceased when no remains...remain.  I would talk to your GM and try and set a milestone for imprisonment along those lines.

In terms of Scrying, I would say that if you have known the person for 6 months or longer you would be considered familiar, as long as you have interacted a decent amount (like adventuring together or working for someone).  But I think Imprisonment would work even on the "secondhand" knowledge scale, as long as you have done research on the subject and can rattle off their name, what they do (not necessarily their class, but their 'job'), and some things of note they've done ("That bartender, Killjoy, once served at the palace making drinks for a big wedding and then got thrown out because he went on a bender himself!") you should be fine getting that -4.

Using the True Resurrection method, knowing the time and place of the character's birth would almost assuredly grant you the -4 as those are some pretty important details of the person's life, as long as you do know their name.

A lot of the higher level spells like this tend to be nebulous because they're meant to be more in the GM's hands than the player's.  It really is something to discuss with your GM outside of game time and figure out what would count, so that you don't get into the discussion when everyone else is there trying to have fun as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, there doesn't seem to be any detailed RAW about this, so I will try to explain how the spell seems to be intended to function.

This spell seems to have two main uses:

- In a fight, as a powerful save-or-be-neutralized used casually by a very powerful caster. An overpowered archmage who cast it on wandering cats because they leave claw marks on the trees in his garden won't care about knowing his enemy. Giving him the -4 would make the spell especially strong with no reason.
- As part of a plan to conceal a dangerous opponent. Usually, the PC won't use it casually, because it is a lvl 9 spell. If they use it it will be from a scroll, or another scenaristic trick. To make sure it succeed they will try to get all the bonuses they can, and this -4 to the save is a nice one.

Considering that, there is two situations:

1. The PCs are lvl 17+, they cast it casually. 
   In this case don't give them the -4 against regular mooks, except if they specifically did research on them or if they have a good reason to know them personally. Usually it won't be the case. Against "boss" mobs, they should have the bonus if it is a recurrent nemesis or a studied target, but not if it is someone they never heard about before. Just knowing the name is not enough, and I would rule that the known facts of his life should be precise. For example "He has killed a thousand people" wouldn't be enough, whereas "He killed Gina's father with his rapier in a duel he cheated" would be.
2. The PCs are lvl 16-, but can have access to this spell by limited/expensive ways. In this case the best is to make it easy for the PC to know enough about any big opponent, at the condition they take the time to search for it. Of course, some villain can have secret identities that would make very difficult their identification, but it should not be the case of everyone. A particularly mysterious campaign boss can even yield to a campaign arc just to get informations about him.